# SQLServer differential backup and restore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a scenario in which I need to maintain a replica of existing database.
Is there a solution to achieve the below mentioned approach. 
1. Take a full back once and restore to a destination database.
2. Scheduled( ex: Every day) differential backup(Only the data which has changed since last backup) of the source database and restore into the destination database

This is to avoid taking full backup and restore each time.

Comment: SQL Server Agent was made for this sort of thing. Any particulars you have trouble with?

Comment: I want to avoid restoring complete backup each time. I just want to restore a differential backup(Changes since last backup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Differential Backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/differential-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), but you would need to ship a new Full backup periodically or the Differentials will continue to grow.

A better solution might be [Log Shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), where  you can ship just the changes on whatever schedule you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider configuring an [availability group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and use a secondary SQL server instance with asynchronous data sync. This should be considered only if the primary(original live SQL server) and secondary servers are in the same location\data centre. So you don't need to take backup-restore or do any extra work other than properly configuring it at the first time.

If that is not the case (copy should be available in another location\data center), it would be better to go with configuring [log shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

First option is a lot better because it would contain the exact copy of the primary database (with a sync delay depending on various factors...probably seconds) and you can directly fail over to the secondary in case of any issues with the primary server.